# Git doesn't detect changes after .git dir moved, returned

Tags: git

I accidentally moved the .git folder out of my working directory before adding & changing some files. When I replaced the .git folder after making the changes, git didn't pick up the changes (I used `git add .`, `git commit -a`). I tried to reproduce the issue and failed. Is there a way to force git to scan for changes in a source tree, or some other way to fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce either. Git doesn't do anything to monitor your working directory, so it should be scanned for changes whenever you use a relevant command.

Comment: I might be missing something, but to "scan for changes in a source tree" you usually use a combination of `git status` and `git diff`

Comment: That's what I understood, but I can't explain why `git status` comes up clean but there are differences between what's local and what's at origin. Same branch etc.

Comment: Does `.git/index` exist? If not, try doing a git checkout <branch name>. It shouldn't overwrite any changed or added files. Git looks at the index to see if files exist or need to be changed/updated and if you removed your `.git` directory and then re-created it that might not exist.

Comment: As an exercise, I backed up & removed the index and ran `checkout -f`. I still have the new files in my directory, but they don't get `add`ed and committed+pushed to origin.

Comment: Have you tried using `git add <file name>` explicitly. Does it say anything? Are they being ignored by a global ignore or a .gitignore in the repo?

Comment: I did try `add`ing files directly, and that doesn't help. They're listed as tracked. The gitignore hasn't changed. I think I'll just revert and manually replace the changes.

Comment: just a wild guess, can you try updating the timestamps? e.g. something like `find . -type f | xargs touch` from the repos root dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to "fit" the new git folder into the project, you should:

1. clone a new repo in the same computer.
2. Put all the old files (all but .git folder) into the new folder.
3. this will give you all the new modified files and new ones listed in 'git status'
4. you now may commit and push them without any issue.

This IMHO is by far the best approach for this awkward case, which i found myself in a couple of times. However will not do if the difference between your repo and the central one it's to big, forcing you to make a megacommit which it's sometimes not desirable.

It's been a long time since you asked, hope this will bring some ligth to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I, unfortunately, do this all the time.  I have a .git repository/directory that I move into and out of numerous 'release versions' (from another VC system).  When I move the .git in, I can perform a 'git status' and find what has changed in the new release.  I then do 'git add -A; git commit -m 'release-xyz'' without any problem.  I can even change branches, w/o a checkout, using 'git symbolic-ref HEAD ...'  When I'm done committing a release, I move the .git out and can do all the 'git diff branch1..branch2' and other operations as well.

So,  I don't see what you described as a problem!